# Looping through array of strings (iterating images)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops

I'm fairly new to Swift and having some trouble iterating through a list of images to animate them. I have all of them named, for instance "aquarium-x", with x being a number from 1-29, depending on how many images I have for the specific animation. This is the code that I have for that part

```
func checkAnimationImages() -> [AnyObject] {
    var i = 0
    var catGifArray = [UIImage]()
    var image = UIImage(named: "-\(i)")
    while (image != nil){
        catGifArray.append(image!)
        ++i
        image = UIImage(named: "-\(i)")
    }
   return catGifArray.map {
        return $0.CGImage as! AnyObject
    }
}
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to also incorporate an array of strings into the UIImage so I don't need to type all the names out.

```
var catGifName:[String] = [
        "3d",
        "piano1",
        "aquarium",
        "bag",
        "bitey",
        "black",
        "blackcat"]
```

I tried to put the name of the array in the "-/(i)" portion but that gives back an error.

Comment: You want the text written into the image?

Comment: No, I want to figure out how to incorporate the array of strings into the function that would iterate through them to animate them. I have a lot of images, named "aquarium-0", "aquarium-1", "aquarium-2"..."aquarium-29", "3d-0"..."3d-5" and so on. I'm trying to figure out a compact way to animate all of them

Comment: I'm sorry - it's tough to figure out exactly what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to take a list of existing names like "aquarium", "3d", etc. and append the "-0", "-1", etc. onto the names, or are you trying to take a list of images that already have the names with the number at the end and figure out a way to cycle through them?

Comment: The latter! Sorry if it's not clear! I'm having trouble wording it

Comment: Let me know if that answer is what you're looking for.  It is tough to word, but I think I get what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you probably need is to pass in your list of filenames, and add the images to the array in a similar manner you were starting.  It'd be something like this:

```
func checkAnimationImages(fileNames: [String]) -> [AnyObject] {
for name in fileNames {
    var i = 0
    var catGifArray = [UIImage]()
    var image = UIImage(named: "\(name)-\(i)")
    while (image != nil){
        catGifArray.append(image!)
        ++i
        image = UIImage(named: "\(name)-\(i)")
    }
}
return catGifArray.map {
    return $0.CGImage as! AnyObject
}
}
```

Of course the `UIImage(named:...)` only works if the image is in the main bundle, but I assume that's how you've set yourself up.

Anyway, you'd call it like...

```
self.checkAnimationImages(self.catGifNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you need is a nested for loop:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
let catGifName = ["cat","piano","aquarium","bag"]
for name in catGifName {
    for i in 1...29 {
        if let image = UIImage(named:"\(name)-\(i)") {
            images.append(image)
        }
    }
}
```